# Connecting devices into sensory network

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns

I know that this question is not about web design or something like that but still I think that it's about usability and UX...

I am thinking about sensory network where I have probably one main application. This application is taking care about this network. Then I have a lot of various devices (sensors) I can connect into this network using ethernet. And the goal is to find the best user friendly way how to connect devices and rename it and configure it in the application.

The problem is, that there is a lot of possible sensors and I don't think it's friendly to connect one sensor, configure it in the application and connect another sensor and so on. How can I handle this problem? Now I am sending information about sensor (type) and UID, but I am afraid that it will not be possible to find out later where the sensor is actualy. Which kind of aditional information I should send or how to improve this proces? I want to open application later, choose first new sensor and say *"oh yeah, this is thermal sensor in the bedroom next to window"* which is one kind of information I actualy cannot send because it's simple sensor and I can't configure it in that specific way (*"under window"* is not for all and this information - UID, type - is in memory by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the sensors' types and UUIDs, I'm afraid there is not much you can do yo identify which one is which. Maybe you can add a button to show the current data the sensor provides:
if it's temperature sensor, you can hold it in your hand to make it hotter, if it's a light sensor, cover it to identify it and so on... But it's rather not intuitive.

It would be nice to know what kind of sensors you have and what available information they can provide in order to find a suitable solution.

A nice solution would have been to press a button (in your app) to make a LED blink on the device or something.
It's easy to implement, clear for the user, fast to identify...

Comment: It depends. But it's on me what the sensor will send. The simpliest example is temperature sensor. This sensor will emit temperature info with time stamp by default. But I like the recommended PING way. It's not the best solution, because the network can be quite big, but it's better than nothing... (-: